# Multiple countdown timer in listview C# duplicating

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, countdowntimer

I'm new to C#.
I'm trying to make a simple task reminder program.
The problem is, when I try to add a countdown for deadline time, it won't work correctly.

My first task countdown will be overwritten by my second task countdown, the same case when I add the third task and so on.

Here is the code of the correlating part.

```
        private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.textBox_Task.Text != "")
        {
            listView1.View = View.Details;
            ListViewItem lvwItem = listView1.Items.Add(dateTimePicker1.Text);
            var day = dateTimePicker1.Value.Day;
            var month = dateTimePicker1.Value.Month;
            var year = dateTimePicker1.Value.Year;

            endTime = new DateTime(year,month,day);

            //Console.WriteLine(day);
            //Console.WriteLine(month);
            //Console.WriteLine(year);
            //Console.WriteLine(dTime

            Timer t = new Timer();
            t.Interval = 500;
            t.Tick += new EventHandler(t_Tick);
            t.Start();

            lvwItem.SubItems.Add(textBox_Task.Text);
            lvwItem.SubItems.Add(textBox_Note.Text);
            lvwItem.SubItems.Add("");
            this.dateTimePicker1.Focus();
            this.textBox_Note.Focus();
            this.textBox_Task.Focus();
            this.textBox_Task.Clear();
            this.textBox_Note.Clear();

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a task to add.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            this.textBox_Task.Clear();
            this.textBox_Note.Clear();
        }
    }

        void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan ts = endTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
        var hari = dateTimePicker1.Value.Day;
        Console.WriteLine(ts.Days);

        for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (ts.Days == 0)
            {
                listView1.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text = "DEADLINE";
            }
            else
            {
                listView1.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text = ts.ToString("d' Days 'h' Hours 'm' Minutes 's' Seconds to go'");
            }
        }

    }
```

It would be much appreciated for anyone who willing to help.
Thanks in advance.

[Here is the link to the picture of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obruQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing now is on each button click override the current endTime object by a new one like:

```
endTime = new DateTime(year,month,day);
```

If you assign a new `DateTime` object to `endTime`. You override the old one. So the first button click will work but the second will create a new object of `DateTime` and assign it `to endTime`. Next you are calculating the time difference on that **one** object `DateTime`. So it is logic that it will be the same time for each listview items

If you want to have more than one `DateTime` use a List to store it in like

```
    List<DateTime> _times = new List<DateTime>();
```

In the button click method add the DateTime to the list

```
  // here add the datetime to the list
  DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(year, month, day);
   _times.Add(dateTime);
```

Next you can loop thru the dates and calculate for each one the time difference in the tick method:

```
        foreach (var dateTime in _times)
        {
            TimeSpan ts = dateTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
            // etc..
        }
```

Also you are creating a timer for each time to calculate after 500 ms. You now can use one timer this is more efficient than crating one for each time. Just assign this in the constructor

```
  public Form1()
  {
        InitializeComponent();

        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.Interval = 500;
        t.Tick += new EventHandler(t_Tick);
        t.Start();
   }
```

Whole code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // This is the list where  the DateTimes are stored so you can have more values
    List<DateTime> _times = new List<DateTime>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Assign the timer here
        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.Interval = 500;
        t.Tick += new EventHandler(t_Tick);
        t.Start();
    }

    private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.textBox_Task.Text != "")
        {
            listView1.View = View.Details;
            ListViewItem lvwItem = listView1.Items.Add(dateTimePicker1.Text);
            var day = dateTimePicker1.Value.Day;
            var month = dateTimePicker1.Value.Month;
            var year = dateTimePicker1.Value.Year;

            // Add Datetime to list
            DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(year, month, day);
            _times.Add(dateTime);

            lvwItem.SubItems.Add(textBox_Task.Text);
            lvwItem.SubItems.Add(textBox_Note.Text);
            lvwItem.SubItems.Add("");
            this.dateTimePicker1.Focus();
            this.textBox_Note.Focus();
            this.textBox_Task.Focus();
            this.textBox_Task.Clear();
            this.textBox_Note.Clear();

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a task to add.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            this.textBox_Task.Clear();
            this.textBox_Note.Clear();
        }
    }
    void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // loop thru all datetimes and calculate the diffrence
        foreach (var dateTime in _times)
        {
            // Call the specific date and subtract on it
            TimeSpan ts = dateTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now);

            var hari = dateTimePicker1.Value.Day;
            Console.WriteLine(ts.Days);

            for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (ts.Days == 0)
                {
                    listView1.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text = "DEADLINE";
                }
                else
                {
                    listView1.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text = ts.ToString("d' Days 'h' Hours 'm' Minutes 's' Seconds to go'");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when i tried this code, it resulting in error which said "The name 'dateTime' does not exist in the current context" in void t_Tick.

Comment: If I try the code no error will be thrown. Could you describe where the error is taking place.

Comment: Sorry it actually thrown no error, but when I run the code, the countdown still having the previous problem, the old countdown still overwritten by the newer one, and so on. Thank you in advance though.